# Filter grouped DataFrame in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a `DataFrame`

```
df = DataFrame(a = [1,1,2,2,2])

5×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a     
     │ Int64 
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     1
   3 │     2
   4 │     2
   5 │     2
```

and I want to filter for the groups with let's say 2 rows - ideally with using `Chain` und potentially using `DataFramesMeta` - and I cannot get it to work.

It does work when first creating a separate column for this like so

```
@chain df begin
    groupby(:a)
    @transform(:rows = length(:a))
    @subset(:rows .== 2)
end

2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      rows  
     │ Int64  Int64 
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      2
   2 │     1      2
```

But it doesn't work when doing the same calculating it within `@subset()`. Anyone got a clever solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my [recent blog post](https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2022/01/28/subset.html) I have explained why we decided that this particular case should not be easily supported (in short: users were confused by pseudo-broadcasting in other cases; however, feel free to open an issue if you disagree with the logic explained there).

The solution is either to use `filter` as Sundar R suggests (in 1.4 release we will add `ungroup` kwarg to it to make it more convenient, see [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl/issues/2954)) or to write:

```
julia> @chain df begin
           groupby(:a)
           @subset(fill(length(:a) == 2, length(:a)))
       end
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ a
     │ Int64
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     1
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to open an issue. I think that DataFrames and DataFramesMeta are making an amazing effort. It's just hard to like this syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `subset`, use `filter` for this:

```
julia> @chain df begin
           groupby(:a)
           filter(:a => a -> length(a) == 2, _)
       end
GroupedDataFrame with 1 group based on key: a
First Group (2 rows): a = 1
 Row │ a     
     │ Int64 
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     1

julia> # OR:

julia> @chain df begin
           groupby(:a)
           filter(_) do subdf
               length(subdf.a) == 2
           end
       end
GroupedDataFrame with 1 group based on key: a
First Group (2 rows): a = 1
 Row │ a     
     │ Int64 
─────┼───────
   1 │     1
   2 │     1
```

Comment: This solution is, without a doubt, worth an up-vote. Unfortunately `filter()` is so hideous in chains, because it puts the object to filter last, that I have a hard time calling this a good solution. But this is, of course, not about you. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Georgery Yeah, `filter` does stand out weirdly in an otherwise nice chain of operations. I've added another version of it, which still *kind of* breaks the flow of the chain, but is at least less hideous in my eyes.

Comment: (Although, I've found that most real world use cases end up with some custom function in the chain that breaks the flow to some extent anyway. Still, it's good to minimize those where we can.)